# What is the word for quoting multiple characters to reenact a scene?

Tags: word-request

What is the word for quoting multiple characters to reenact a scene? I was thinking of a word like "quote", but I am not sure you can use it if **a single person** "quote" multiple characters at once in different voice. Some humorists do it.

For example:

> "Pikachu, thundershock!"
>
> "Pika, pika!"
>
> "Pikachu, now! What are you waiting for?"
>
> "Pika, pika?"

Comment: Are you talking about a specific word for quoting dialog? Reenact is probably your best bet.

Comment: Those are completely disconnected quotes. Who is saying what? What's the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Reenact"** is solid, and you can give, do, provide, or perform a **"reenactment"**. But a **"recreation"** might be a hair more natural, so you might **"recreate"** the events or the exchange.

Doing or giving an **"impression"** calls to mind the skill of the performer in approximating the voices and mannerisms of a person.  **"Imitating"** can be done to a group of people, or (more commonly) a single person - compare the noun "mimicry".

A person might **"relate"** a conversation, dialogue, or back-and-forth (*informal*), along with a whole host of more general terms including "relay", "convey", "act out", etc.